# Use lineout on Mac for audio processing

Tags: mac, audio

Does anyone know of a way to set the linein on a Mac to route from the lineout?  I want to essentially work with the music played on my Mac.  An alternative solution I suppose would be to set the Linein as the output from iTunes/other music player.

For context:
My specific use-case is audio processing in Processing with the *minim* library, calling getLineIn.  Trying to create some visuals that respond to the music being played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the default output device temporarily to a [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/) device. In the application used to record or process the input, set the input device to Soundflower and the output device to a normal output.

[image]